# How can I change the left large margin to appear on odd pages, rather the even pages

Tags: margins, double-sided, classicthesis

The print shop has asked that I produce my document to have large margins on the left for odd pages. This makes sense, since when opening the book the first printed page will appear on the right.

How can I change this behaviour of classicthesis? Furthermore, why does classicthesis default to printing the first page with a large margin on the right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In most quality book the wider margin is the outer one.

Comment: Probably what you need is a binding correction.

Comment: Let me guess, you have very small margns.  Anyway, \oddsidemargin and \evensidemargin can be set independently.  The TeX engine adds a 1in margin automatically, but you can specify a negative value to compensate.  The right margin is not set, but simply consists of whatever is left over.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Done. I hope I've done it right. (I don't use the KOMA stuff except to answer questions!)

Comment: @cfr Ta. Ta. Ta.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are using a KOMA class since you are using `classicthesis`. If you are using a standard class, see below.

## KOMA class

Here's some code for a Minimum Working Example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following default layout:

[image: default]

To specify a binding correction, we can pass the relevant value as an option to the class, provided we are using a KOMA class (e.g. `scrbook`).

Suppose we want a binding correction of 25mm. (This is large, I think. I doubt the print shop needs this much for the binding.)

```
\documentclass[BCOR=25mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Now a double-page spread looks like this:

[image: binding correction of 25mm]

## Standard class

If we are using a standard class (e.g. `book`), then the default layout looks like this:

[image: standard default]

We can't pass the binding correction as a class option this time but this isn't a problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\typearea[25mm]{last}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: binding correction with standard class]

Hopefully your pages do not look *quite* like this but the above should be enough to enable you to modify your document. If not, please include a small,compilable document (MWE), like that above, which will enable us to better understand the context of your question.